Automatic Image Annotation Based On Colour
I need to annotate a large corpus of images for image segmentation.
I can generate this corpus of images myself and I can choose to color whatever needs to be annotated with a specific colour.
I would like to know if there is any way to automatically annotate based off of colour for a machine learning task?
